# Graphs where every maximal clique has the same size

Tags: graph-theory

I have a family of (simple,  regular, vertex-transitive) graphs and believe that each graph in the family has the property that every maximal clique has the same size.

What are some necessary or sufficient conditions for every maximal clique in a graph to have the same size?

Does this property have a name?

Thank you

Comment: You mention your graphs are vertex transitive? Doesn't every graph which is vertex transitive have that property? If $u$ is a vertex where its maximum clique it is a member has a different size than the maximum clique that contains vertex $v$ , then there cannot be an automorphism which takes $u$ to $v$.

Comment: @JoshuaZ Two maximal cliques of different sizes can share a vertex ...

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Ah yes, good point.

Comment: A graph with every maximal independent set having the same size is called  “well covered” so you have the complete of a well-covered graph.

Comment: @JoshuaZ The [triangular prism graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_prism) is vertex-transitive and has maximal cliques of order $2$ and $3$.

Comment: @Gordon Royle Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for. Based on your answer, I see this paper: https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/72/ajc_v72_p273.pdf by Finbow and Whitehead, which promises to explain everything to me.